# How to make the textview content HORIZONTAL

Tags: android

I need dynamic create the texview, it works just the text content show `VERTICAL` but  `HORIZONTAL`

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this.theContext);
    tv.setText(this.getTip(0));
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    tv.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        this.addView(tv, params);

    mLeftLabel = tv;
```

also, I set the layout :

`tv.layout(l,t,r,b);` . but I think that this statement should not effect the text Direction, is it right ?

please give help or tip, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to follow the example below:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("text");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
mainLayout.addView(tv, params);
```

Comment: still not work, the text string show 'list' but in a 'row'... confuse.

Comment: Please, show the code of your Activity and xml file. Also please try to explain again, what exactly is a problem.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand what do you mean here: "it works just the text content show VERTICAL but  HORIZONTAL".

Comment: I meaning the text show as VERTICAL but HORIZONTAL...

now, I have use draw text but a TextView ... thanks for your time, 

I guess it seem cause the layout of the parent view , anyway, the layout of Android is hard to use not easy than iOS develop

Answer (score 0):

try changing LayoutParams as

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

setting gravity to center when you are using WRAP_CONTENT for textview does not seem to make sense, though I am not sure.